# Change my database result to JSON

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

I would like to know how to get the result of my query to be a JSON response in Node.js. Currently, I am getting a result from my DB that is in JSON but I cannot access the values in it. My code is below.

```
connection.connect();

connection.query('select * from ttnews order by post_date DESC Limit 0,10', 
function (error, results, fields) {
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
responseJSON.response = results[0].headline; 
callback(null, responseJSON);
```

By the line `responseJSON.response = results[0].headline` I am getting an error `results is undefined`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can you provide full code of your method? Do you use `express`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **Express 4.x**, the output rows from **mysql db** is in **json** format.

**For example,**

```
sqlConnect.connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Querying error");
    } else {
        console.log(rows);
    }
    sqlConnect.connection.end();
});
```

The output is of the form

```
[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    username: 'Dani',
    password: '1q2w3e4r',
    verified: 0 } ]
```

So now you can get the individual values using the **. operator**. For example, console.log(rows[0].username)  will log the value 'Dani'

Comment: This works as it did before however when I try to add a value to a JSON variable but for some reason, I get rows is not defined. Please see my code `responseJSON.response = rows[0].username;` This is done outside of the sqlConnect function, note if I replace `rows[0].username` with a string it works fine.

Comment: Can u update your question with full snippet of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I find **results** arrays is outside the scope so it shows **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var readline = require('readline');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
host : 'localhost',
user : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'cmd'//your database name
});
con.connect(function(err){
if(err){
console.log('Error Connecting to Database');
}
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
con.query('SELECT * FROM ttnews order by post_date DESC Limit 0,10',function(error, data){
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }else{
            res.json(data)
        } 
    }); 
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log('server listening on 3000');
});
```

Hope this helps...